# C implementation for generic function with varargs

Tags: c

I need to write the implementation of a function that accept as parameters:

- a function pointer
- a list of parameters

The function prototype should be something like this :

```
void caller_imp( generic_function_pointer, varargs_list )
```

Suppose you have the following code example:

```
#define caller(function, ...) caller_imp(function, __VA_ARGS__)

int test (int a)
{
    return a;
}

int test2(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

void caller_imp(???,???)
{
    ???
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    caller(test,33);
    
    caller(test2,44,55);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Of consequence im in need to write the proper implementation of the "caller_imp" function.

UPDATED DETAILS :

```
int test (int a)
```

```
int test2(int a, int b)
```

are only an example, the function pointer and the parameters coul be varying, for example :

```
int test3(int a,char *str)
```

should be considered valid

unfortunatly I dont know which function pointer will be called or the number of the parameters or their type.

In C++ I think I could do :

```
template<typename Function, typename... Params>
auto call_imp(Function function, Params... params)
->typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<void,decltype(function(params...))>::value,decltype(function(params...))>::type
{
    function(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `printf` function gets number and types of parameters in format string. Do you know the number and types of vararg parameters in advance? It's something your caller function needs to know.

Comment: @user694733 in other situations i have used something like this :

`va_list argp;
va_start(argp, str);
vfprintf(stdout, str, argp);
va_end(argp);`

etc...

in his case unfortunatly I dont know the number of receiving parameters.

Comment: There's `stdarg.h` which allows you to write variadic functions. Which I strongly advise not to do, it leads to plain bad and dangerous program design.

Comment: did you consider `#define caller(function, ...) (function)(__VA_ARGS__)` ?

Comment: C is not intended to support flexible function calls like this. If `caller_imp` is provided with some means of knowing what arguments the called function expects, you can write specific code for **each** case to be supported. Otherwise, C does not support dynamically constructing argument lists. There are non-portable means of doing so (including a library for it somebody on Stack Overflow linked to within the past few months, if I recall correctly, but I do not expect to be able to find that easily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in the C standard because there is no information available about what parameters a function expects. That is, given a function pointer alone, we cannot know whether the function expects one `int` argument, two `int` arguments, one `int` and one `char *` argument, or something else. Therefore, even if we had a way to dynamically construct an argument list, we would not know which argument list to construct.

If you do know which function requires which arguments, you can write specific code for each case:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void caller_imp(void (*f)(void),...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, f);
    if (f == (void (*)(void)) test)
    {
        int a = va_arg(ap, int);
        ((int (*)(int)) f)(a);
    }
    else if (f == (void (*)(void)) test2)
    {
        int a = va_arg(ap, int);
        int b = va_arg(ap, int);
        ((int (*)(int, int)) f)(a, b);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Then the `caller` macro should convert the function pointer:

```
#define caller(function, ...) caller_imp((void (*)(void))(function), __VA_ARGS__)
```

If you do not know which function requires which arguments, it would be necessary to provide this information in some way, such as creating an enumeration of function types and requiring the caller to provide it.

Comment: i agree with your answer, writing each case for the conversion is not a suitable solution for me.
Like user Lundind noted, i agree too that forcing to be type generic at all costs is not always the best solution.

Comment: consider replacing `((int (*)(int)) f)(a);` with `test(a)`. It may be a bit easier to read

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to allow either 1 or 2 arguments of type `int`:

```
#define COUNT_ARGS(...) ( sizeof (int[]){__VA_ARGS__} / sizeof(int) )
#define caller(function, ...) (COUNT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__) == 1 ? function : function##2) (__VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage:

```
caller(test, 1);
caller(test, 1, 2);
```

Please note that error handling is pretty non-existent here though...

Comment: Better to name the function `test0`, `test1` and `test2`, that would be more straight forward to implement.

Comment: this solution can work only if i have this 2 functions (test and test2 ), unfortunatly i dont know which function pointer will be called and the number of the parameters or their type.
im updating the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Honneamise The correct solution is very likely to make sure you know. Type-generic programming is often misguided and the wrong solution to a problem. To know the correct one you have to go back to the overall program design.

Comment: @Lundin of course i was aware that to be so type genereic is not always a good practice, so i asked during my planning fase and im now switching to a more comfortable design.
Thank you.